# Hadoop Command For Listing Files

Tags: hadoop, command, hdfs

Hadoop command for listing files is

```
hadoop fs -ls.
```

When I go to hadoop folder on my desktop and type in this command I get the following message

```
hadoop: command not found
```

I am not sure how to circumvent this problem. Your suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: I tried out bin/hadoop fs -ls and I get this ten tries and then a fail as given below

Comment: 13/09/21 13:32:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
ls: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Is your Hadoop up and running?

Comment: It is, I have all the daemons running in pseudo distributed mode. It looks like I have to enter the commands the following way : bin/hadoop fs -ls. That works. For some reason it does not work if I leave out the bin part.

Comment: Did you add `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` to the `PATH` ?

Comment: I probably did not. Can you please tell me how to do that. I guess I can research that but...

Comment: Assuming you use bash. Edit ~/.bashrc : export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop/dir  .. export PATH=$PATH:[...]:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

Comment: @LorandBendig  Thanks a bunch. That fixed my problems with bin/, appreciate your response....

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with hadoop Path:

In Linux
You can set Hadoop environment variables by appending the following commands to `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

In Windows:
Nicely explained steps with image:[Here](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10) 
In OS environment variable set home path as

```
HADOOP_HOME=c:\hadoop\bin  (/path/to/hadoop/dir)
```

List the contents of the root directory in HDFS
#

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```